# Run Sp on linked server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, linked-server

How could i run my sp on a linked server ? Using sql-server-2008

```
Exec my_sp [db-srv_name].[db-name].[dbo]
```

Please help me i am new in sql

Answer (score 1):

Yes you execute stored procedure via linked server.

The EXECUTE statement must contain the name of the linked server as part of its syntax.

Syntax **EXECUTE servername.dbname.owner.procedure_name**

e.g `EXEC [KAP-PC\SQL2012DXD02].[master].[dbo].[sp_helpserver]`

where sp_helpserver is the stored procedure on the master DB with owner as DBO and server name KAP-PC\SQL2012DXD02

Another Method would be Using Distributed Query functions (OpenQuery())

Syntax: **SELECT *FROM OPENQUERY([RemoteServer],DatabaseName.DatabaseOwner.StoredProcedureName)**

e.g

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY([KAP-PC\SQL2012DXD02],AdventureWorks.dbo.spAdmin_GetAllUsers)
```